# How do websites use information on a database to create pages?

Tags: database, dynamic

Sorry about the broad question. I'm just curious if someone could point me in the right direction.

Say there's a database of contact information, and there's a site where you can input a persons name and it brings you to a page with all of their information on that database. How does this happen exactly? The server would have to dynamically create this page, but does it have a generic format that it just fills with the information? And how does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, this is a an extremely broad question. It could be either way. The server could generate the entire contents dinamically, or it could be "filling the blanks" into a preformatted layout.

Google some PHP basic tutorials. That should give you a good idea about how this "dynamism" works. Sorry but your question is too broad to ellaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

The server would dynamically create the page using PHP and SQL.  There is a quick tutorial at http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/ that shows how it would be setup.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you are asking things like how this page was created, for example, in which case it can be as simple as a basic PHP and SQL combination. You can check an example on the w3sschools [website](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp):

[Try it yourself example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo)

There would be special place holders for the data and a query will extract the data and put it into the given place holders, please note, you can also use loops to add things like tables, fetch through multiple rows and so on.